# how to change a different element of a 2d numpy array each time

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-slicing

I have a numpy 2d array (matrix):

```
[[1,2,3],
 [4,5,6],
 [7,8,9]]
```

and i want to change the values based on this vector-mask

```
[0,2,1]
```

hence i want to change the values of

```
1, 6 and 8
```

to for example

```
2, 9 and 24
```

the vector is as long as the matrix is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can index the rows with an `arange` to go along with your column mask indexes:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9],
])

rows = np.arange(len(a))
columns = [0, 2, 1]
values = [2, 9, 24]

a[rows, columns] = values
```

Output:

```
array([[ 2,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  9],
       [ 7, 24,  9]])
```